# How to properly configure jquery-ui datepicker max/min range and initialize default from Rails column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jquery-ui datepicker on a User DOB field in a Rails 3.2 app.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. restrict the range of dates that can be selected, max = today, min = 100 years ago.
2. initialize the datepicker with the date currently stored in the database (if any).
3. display the selected date in a particular format in the dob text field.

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :dob, :class=>'date-selector-dob', :value => (@user.dob.blank? ? '' : @user.dob.to_s(:long))  %>
<% end %>
```

where `.to_s(:long)` is the display format I'm after.

With the following javascript the datepicker works, the text field is properly formatted, but no max/ min date is set, and no initialization with the stored date occurs.

```
$(function (){  // enabledate picker
    $('.date-selector-dob').datepicker();
});
```

I added to this functions that I though would set min/max range and initialize, as follows:

```
$(function (){  // enable date picker
    $('.date-selector-dob').datepicker({minDate: new Date('-100Y'), maxDate: new Date('-1D')}); // enable datepicker and set range
    $('.date-selector-dob').datepicker('setDate', new Date($('.date-selector-dob').attr('value'))); // initialize datepicker with stored value

});
```

This **is** initializing the date picker correctly, but **is not** setting a min/max range. Is my approach incorrect?

In addition, the extended function resets my formatting string, and data is not displayed according to `.to_s(:long)`. Using the basic function above, this formatting string is properly applied. What would cause this?

I'm pulling my hair out with this! I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me see whatever is it I've missed, and understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's `Date` doesn't know what `-100Y` or `-1D` mean so your `minDate` and `maxDate` settings aren't going to be anything that the datepicker will understand.

From the [fine manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate):

> **minDate**
>
> Set a minimum selectable date via a Date object or as a string in the current `dateFormat`, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '-1y -1m'), or null for no limit.

So you want this:

```
 $('.date-selector-dob').datepicker({
     minDate: '-100y',
     maxDate: '-1d'
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RQgCW/

If you want the datepicker to use a certain format for the date, use the `dateFormat` option:

> The format for parsed and displayed dates. This attribute is one of the regionalisation attributes. For a full list of the possible formats see the `formatDate` function.

Also, you should be able to skip this:

```
$('.date-selector-dob').datepicker('setDate', new Date($('.date-selector-dob').attr('value')))
```

and just set the `<input>`'s `value` attribute to the date (preferably in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) format), then the datepicker should be able to take it from there on its own.

Comment: Thanks mu, saving me again! min/max are now working as expected. I'm confused by the display format issue though. This relates to the text field that is displaying the date string. As such, shouldn't the formatting be handled by rails? I'm confused as to why adding the setDate method should stop this working, when it works fine without this method?

Comment: @AndyHarvey: Your best bet is to start the date in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) format, then tell the datepicker which format you want it to use. The datepicker will write the date into the text input so it needs to know what format to use. ISO 8601 will be easy for the datepicker to parse. And you shouldn't need that `setValue` call, just setting the `<input>`'s value should be sufficient.

Comment: Oh, by the way, dateFormat does solve the issue. But I'm still curious as to why the format defined in Rails is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of initialize datepicker object we need to pass all our conditions as a hash. In your example you datepicker initialized for second time, that's the problem for not getting date range.

```
$(function (){  
        $('.date-selector-dob').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'M dd, yyyy',
                minDate: '-1y',
                maxDate: '+1m',
        });
});
```

You can set the date by following way, for this you need to specify correct date format(already specified in initializer param as 'dateFormat')

```
$('#popupDatepicker').val("Feb 13, 2012");
```